# InAppWebView - inject text in the html

Tags: flutter, webview

I am using flutter_inappwebview. I need to insert text into the content of the page loaded with the initialUrl. I don't want to use loadData because I need to load from an url.

The text is the content of the file that the user opens via a button widget.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using loadData with a baseUrl. That way I still load the url with the custom data that I need.

Besides, one can also insert values using evaluateJavascript:

```
onChanged: (String value) async {
             await webView.evaluateJavascript(
                 source: "document.getElementById('element-id').value = '$value'; ");
          },
```